# How to configure eclipse che to use https?

Tags: https, eclipse-che

I have been using eclipse che for a few days and would like to enable https on it. I did not find any reliable information on how one would start eclipse che in https mode. I looked into che.env and could not find anything.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I've been using using che over a ssh tunnel using putty tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Che does not officially support https.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy to OpenShift/K8s and have TLS support. But not on Docker